# problem in using OAuth for Twitter

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I have implemented OAuth for twitter using Abraham Williams php library. It is working fine for me on personal web server(Apache). But when I uploaded all my application files to a public web hosting domain, it stops working. When I press the button 'sign in with twitter account' that directs user to 'connect.php' which builds twitter link to authenticate my application,  it doesn't build the link. Rather control halts on that 'connect.php' page. Here is connect.php

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'twitteroauth/TwitterOAuth.php';
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "***************");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "********************************");

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken('http://babar.phpnet.us/callback.php');

$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] =
$request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

$url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($request_token);
header('Location: ' . $url);
?>
```

Here is callback.php

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'twitteroauth/TwitterOAuth.php';
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "****************");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "*********************************");

if (
    isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']) 
    && $_SESSION['oauth_token'] !== $_REQUEST['oauth_token']) 
    {
     //echo 'Session expired';
     header('Location: ./connect.php');
    }
  else {
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,
        $_SESSION['oauth_token'],$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = 
        $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);
        header('Location: index1.php');
       }
 ?>
```

index1.php

```
  if (empty($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
     header('Location: ./connect.php');
    }

     require_once 'twitteroauth/TwitterOAuth.php';
     define("CONSUMER_KEY", "**************");
     define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "*******************");

     $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,
     $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token'],
     $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret']
    );

    include("index.php");
    $tweetmsg = $_POST['t_update'];
    $result = $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $tweetmsg));
      if (200 === $connection->http_code) {
         //echo'tweet posted';
         }
       else {
             $resultmsg = 'Could not post Tweet. Error: '.$httpCode.'  
             Reason:'.$result->error; 
             //echo $resultmsg;
        }
     ?>
```

Comment: Same version of PHP in both locations? Check with <?php phpinfo(); ?>. PHP4 in one place and PHP5 in the other could be a problem. After that, I'd start looking at differences between included libraries: cURL, etc. ...

Comment: @ebynum, its PHP Version 5.2.12 on the web hosting domain.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the clock on the server is properly synced with [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol). If the time differers from the clocks on Twitter's servers by more then five minutes requests will fail.

You should also check to see if there is a firewall blocking https://api.twitter.com.

Comment: I think there is no firewall issue as I run it from my laptop that has no firewall installed with same results. How do I Make sure the clock on the server is properly synced with NTP.I find a 'ntpq -p' to find all configured clock sources But I donot have access to shell on my web hosting server. Are these two the possible problems? If you see connect.php, there is no error handler code, can you mention what error handling code could be added so that info about error is available. Currently, control is just halted on connect.php

Comment: So it is not working on your laptop or on the public web server but it works on a different apache install somewhere? Check to make sure you have PHP 5.2+ cURL, and OpenSSL installed and working on each server/computer.

Comment: I have same problem but with firewall blocking. 

Wich part of csf (firewall) is related to oauth->getRequestToken method?